# A sequence of $x_n \in (0,1)$ such that $x_n \to 1$ with explicit $|x_n-x_k|$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am looking for a sequence of $x_n \in (0,1)$  such that

1.$x_n \to 1$

1. we have an explicit form for  $|x_n-x_k|$  for every $n$ and $k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_n := 1 - \frac{1}{n},$$
$$|x_n - x_k|  = |1 - \frac{1}{n} - 1 + \frac{1}{k}| = \frac{|n - k|}{nk}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can check easily that if

$$x_n=\frac 12+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}$$

then
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n=\frac 12\frac{1}{1-\frac 12}=1$$

and for $ n>k,$

$$|x_n-x_k|=\sum_{i=k+1}^n\frac{1}{2^i}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2^{k}}(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-k}})$$

Answer (score 0):

For instance, $x_n=\cos\sin\frac{(-1)^n}n$ will do.

$\left\lvert x_n-x_k\right\rvert=\left\lvert \cos\sin\frac{(-1)^n}n-\cos\sin\frac{(-1)^k}k\right\rvert$.